# How to use aggregate functions (avg, count, max, min) using sqlbuilder.smartsql

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find a way to use aggregate function in Postgres using sqlbuilder.smartsql (python library).
But I am not able to do that.

Documentation doesn't have any use case as well :
https://sqlbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I tried using below :

`q = q.fields(e(func.avg(T.author.age))`

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'func' is not defined

Tried a few more ways, but no luck.

Questions :

1. Is the use of aggregate functions supported in sqlbuilder.smartsql
2. If the aggregate functions are supported in any way, can someone share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the way for calling aggregate function (or any other postgres functions)

````
>>> q
<Query: SELECT *, AVG("author"."age") FROM "author", []>```
````